# Micronaut calling MongoDB functions

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, micronaut, micronaut-data

I have been search this for a while, I can't seems to find the correct way to call mongoDB functions in Micronaut application. `MongoOperations` and `MongoTemplate` are not available, and using `MongoClient`***eval*** function is also deprecated. Do I have to use 3rd party libraries to call MongoDB functions in Micronaut? Please point me to the right direction. thank you.

Comment: Can you provide an example or explanation of what you mean by "MongoDB functions"?

Comment: Sorry, I mean to say Mongo db JavaScript functions some query logics, or it can be the function that runs a aggregation to create a materialized view, but if the functions are saved on the server side how do I call them. Thanks.

Comment: are you saving javascript functions in the MongoDB collection? If possible include an example exactly what you trying to do

Comment: No I'm trying to run this. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/server-side-javascript/

Comment: did you tried `$function` using aggregation?

Comment: I found the document regarding `$function`. Thank you!